# How to do this in Groovy Range Object?

Tags: groovy

I want numbers from 0.1 to 2(such as 0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4 so on to 2.0), as I'm a groovy guy i decided `Range` will do the job, and came with code like this:

```
def a = 0.1..2
println a
```

But its printing only `[0.1, 1.1]` as its output! So i can't do this in `Range`? or by syntax is wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Also, see this previous familiar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/573155/groovy-range-with-a-0-5-step-size

Answer (score 6, accepted):

that's not trivial. The range object has a step method, but this allows only for integer steps.
Another solution could be to define your own range object.

If a list is also ok, you can use the step method on a number:

```
0.1.step(2, 0.1){ print "$it "}
```

another solution:

```
(1 .. 20).collect{it/10}
```

Comment: Oh But in Groovy in Action(first edition its say's its possible!)... And the answer posted by Boris wont work!

Comment: found it. It seems there was a change. In the first edition, you'll find an example `assert (0.0..1.0).contains(0.5)` which has been changed to `assert (0.0..1.0).contains(0.5) == false` in the second edition of the book.

Comment: how does `step` method works in the first case? actually  `step` method is used for?

Comment: @Ant: see http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/lang/Number.html#step%28java.lang.Number,%20java.lang.Number,%20groovy.lang.Closure%29

Comment: And one more help, if you have Groovy in action second edition ebook, can you mail me that(if you don't mind!) ^_^

Comment: YOu can buy the Groovy in action second edition MEAP (Manning Early Access Program): http://manning.com/koenig2/ . The prices for the MEAP are great and if you subscribe to the Deal of the Day mailing list, chances are good to even get a better price: http://manning.com/free/dotd.html