# Generate a list of number with interval in Groovy

Tags: groovy

I'm learning Groovy. I want an array of numbers from 0 to n with interval 0.1.

```
double arr=[0,0.1,0.2....n]
```

I could write a java style for-loop, but is there a easier syntax to do this? I know Groovy has a lot of syntactic sugar.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Groovy range with a 0.5 step size](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/573155/groovy-range-with-a-0-5-step-size)

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/573155/groovy-range-with-a-0-5-step-size and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6715686/how-to-do-this-in-groovy-range-object

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would go with `0.0..10.0.collect{it/10.0}` but maybe there is clever way to do it by specifying increments.

Answer (score -1):

there was an exact question here earlier

n=10;(0..10*n).collect{it/10}

there are no decimal step values for Groovy's ranges
currently

Comment: *there are no decimal step values for Groovy's ranges currently*

- this is untrue, see my answer