# How can I customize grails select tag

Tags: select, grails, gsp

I want to customize grails select tag

I tried this code

```html
<g:select name="totalHour" from="${1..20}" value="${holdingVacationInstance}"/>
```

this code select options look like this

> 1, 2, 3, ... , 20

then, how can i make like this

> 0.5, 1.0, 1.5, ... , 20.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use like this

```
<g:select name="totalHour" from="${(0.5..20).step(1)}" value="${holdingVacationInstance}"/>
```

Then it will give output like `[0.5, 1.5, 2.5, 3.5, ...]` as per my concern you can't use non integer step. See here http://grails.asia/groovy-range-examples

Answer (score 0):

Using the 'from' attribute you'll either have to give the select options as a list or as a Groovy Range.

IMO the latter is a more solid way to go:

[Groovy range with a 0.5 step size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/573155/groovy-range-with-a-0-5-step-size)